# Proper Terms For Representing GPS Coordinates

Tags: usage, kana, kana-usage

In [another question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4606/sokuon-diacritic-and-wabun-morse-code), I mentioned using Kana to represent the GPS coordinates for:

```
N 43° 09.725' W 077° 26.688'
```

I used:

```
キタ シジュウ サン ジスウ ク チョボ ナナヒャク ニジュウ ゴ フン
kita shijuu san jisuu ku chobo nanahyaku nijuu go fun

ニシ ナナジュウ シチ ジスウ ニジュウ ロコ チョボ ロッピャク キュウジュウ ハチ フン
nishi nanajuu shichi jisuu nijuu roku chobo roppyaku kyuujuu hachi fun
```

Are the terms that I used for north, west, degree, decimal, and minutes correct in the context that I'm using them?

- north | kita | キタ
- west | nishi | ニシ
- degrees | jisuu  | ジスウ
- decimal | chobo | チョボ
- minutes | fun | フン

Comment: Where did you get チョボ from? I've never heard it before, but maybe it's seafarer lingo or something?

Comment: With your level of knowledge about Japanese, you will not be able to produce something at a satisfactory level. You may want to learn from the "all your base are belong to us"-incident.

Comment: As @sawa pointed out, my level of knowledge is very limited. My technique for finding these words was to look at an [online dictionary](http://www.freedict.com/onldict/jap.html) and search for the English words and then plug the Japanese words back into the translation to complete the round trip. I selected words that seemed most like what I was looking for.

Comment: “N 43° 09.725' W 077° 26.688'” is read as 北緯43度9.725分西経77度26.688分 (ほくいよんじゅうさんどきゅうてんななにごふん せいけいななじゅうななどにじゅうろくてんろくはちはちふん).

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto So the last digit after the decimal does not undergo sound modification by the counter? I'll delete that from my answer...

Comment: @Hyperworm: ～はっぷん may be correct.  Somehow I have a habit of reading 8 as はち when everyone else reads はっ (and this happens only with 8).

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I'm going around looking at comment-answers. Would you like to post your comment as an answer instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`次数` (jisuu) seems to be "degree" in the [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29) sense, not as in angles. I've never heard `ちょぼ` used for "decimal point", but perhaps I'm ignorant here.

The terms I would use are `度` (do) and `点` (ten) respectively. `コンマ` (comma) is also heard as a decimal point separator (even when the symbol `,` is not used).

Note that, as in English, numbers after a decimal point should be spelled out individually, not using a place system:

English: `.688` is read e.g. `point six eight eight` not `point six hundred and eighty eight`.
Japanese: `.688` is read e.g. `てん ろく　はち　はち` not `てん　ろっぴゃく　はちじゅう　はち`.